# Can I use variable with value from some function

Tags: mysql

Is there legal way of using variable like that :

```
SELECT dr.id, @diff:=DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(dr.dt, INTERVAL dr.payment_session DAY))
FROM `dst_request` as dr
WHERE @diff >= 0 OR @diff <=5
```

It doesn't throw errors like that but it also doesn't return the proper result. Is it valid query ? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you mis-tagged this question

Comment: Yep. Sorry about that.

Comment: And donwvoted because ?

Comment: I think you should use a derived table instead

Comment: Ok will search information about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a derived table:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    diff
FROM (
        SELECT
            dr.id,
            DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(dr.dt, INTERVAL dr.payment_session DAY)) as diff
         FROM `dst_request` as dr
) as t
WHERE diff >= 0 OR diff <=5
```

Forgive me if there's a syntax or formatting error, as I transcribe this using my phone while in the bathtub. The concept is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a valid query yes it's syntactically correct but in the order of operations the where clause is applied before the select so @diff is probably null when the where clause is executed, you could apply the calculation in the where clause to overcome this.

```
SELECT dr.id, DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(dr.dt, INTERVAL dr.payment_session DAY)) diff
FROM `dst_request` as dr
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(dr.dt, INTERVAL dr.payment_session DAY)) >= 0 
OR DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE_ADD(dr.dt, INTERVAL dr.payment_session DAY)) <=5
```

https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/